# Unable to read object property

Tags: reactjs

I'm a bit confused why I'm unable to read the property of an object in my React component.

Here's my if statement which is failing because member.firstName is "undefined".

When I check to see if my "member" object has any data in it, this is what I see:
[image]

Here's what the object and its properties look like and the firstName property has a value in it:
[image]

But the when I try to access the value of the first name property in my if statement, I'm getting "undefined" for first name and the if statement is failing.

Why is that?

One thing I noticed is that member appears to be an array. So I tried accesing it with `member[0].firstName` which also threw an error.

Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: As your debugger says, `member` is an array with one single element inside, so you need to access it with `member[0].firstName`. What error does it throw accessing it that way? Can you please show us your React code?

Comment: The error I get is Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined